# ReactJS Formulario - Error en Submit

Tags: reactjs, formularios, botón, submit

al rellenar un formulario de login tengo un problema y es que al darle a submit reinicia la página y no se ejecuta el eventListener

```
        const form = document.getElementById('loginForm');
    if (form) {
        form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            this.login();
        });
    };
```

Si creo un botón aparte que al pulsarlo ejecute la función `this.login()` todo funciona correctamente.
Estoy aprendiendo con React y no se como hacer que se ejecute la función al ejecutar el input de tipo submit. Gracias de antemano

Comment: Puedes por favor mostrar el como estas creando tu formulario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te recomiendo que leas [la documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button), de donde resalto los atributos del elemento botón:

> The default behavior of the button. Possible values are:
>
> submit: The button submits the form data to the server. This is the
> default if the attribute is not specified for buttons associated with
> a , or if the attribute is an empty or invalid value.
>
> reset: The button resets all the controls to their initial values,
> like . (This behavior tends to annoy users.)
>
> button: The button has no default behavior, and does nothing when
> pressed by default. It can have client-side scripts listen to the
> element's events, which are triggered when the events occur.

Tomando esto en cuenta creo que lo que necesitas es definir el botón con un atributo `type` que tenga el valor de `button`. Y para poder invocar la función que necesitas utiliza el evento `onClick` y pasa como parámetro tu función de JS.